# Individual column searching on Server side DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to apply individual column searching.In footer dropdown column only first page option are shown and on selecting any option it cann't filter any record.I want that all records will be shown in dropdown colum.On Client side table code is working properly.

```
function CallToServer() {
                oTable = $('#' + tableId).dataTable({

                    //'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
                    "sScrollY": "auto",
                    'bPaginate': true,
                    'iDisplayLength': 10,
                    'bProcessing': true,
                    "bStateSave": true,
                    'bFilter': true,
                    'bServerSide': true,
                    "language": {
                        "searchPlaceholder": "Search",
                        "lengthMenu": "Showing _MENU_ Projects",
                        "zeroRecords": "Sorry no Project(s) found",
                        "info": "Showing _START_ of _END_ of _TOTAL_ Projects",
                        "infoEmpty": "No Project(s) found",
                        "infoFiltered": "(filtered from MAX total Projects)"
                    },
                    "aaSorting": [[2]],
                    "aoColumns": [
                       { "bSortable": true, "bvsible": false },
                        { "bSortable": true, "class": "test" },
                        { "bSortable": true, "class": "test" },
                        { "bSortable": true, "class": "test" },
                        { "bSortable": true, "class": "test" },
                        //{ "bSortable": true, "class": "test" }
                       ],
                    responsive: true,
                    'sAjaxSource': ws_GetData,
                    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) { GrabData(sSource, aoData, fnCallback); }
                    , initComplete: function () {

                        this.api().columns().every(function () {

                                var column = this;
                                var select = $('<select><option value="">All Projects</option></select>')
                                    .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                                    .on('change', function () {
                                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                            $(this).val()
                                        );

                                        column
                                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)

                                            .draw();
                                    });
                                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                                    //var anchor = d;
                                    //anchor = anchor.substring(anchor.indexOf(">") + 1);
                                    //anchor = anchor.substring(0, anchor.indexOf("<"));
                                    //alert(anchor);


                                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                                });


                        });
                    }
                });



                $('#' + tableId + ' tbody tr').live('click', function () {

                    $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function () { $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected'); });

                    $(this).addClass('row_selected');

                    //var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
                    //var aData = oTable.fnGetData(this);
                    //iId = aData[0];
                });
            }
```